# Shopify - Jquery not loading first

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a countdown timer to my product page. It loads fine when I go from a link in my store to the product, but when I try and use a direct link I get: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at "product name"

I have added my jquery above all else in the app.js.liquid section of my store and I am still getting the error. I don't really know what else to try at this point and any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks allot!

Comment: please add some code to your question to help others help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should place your jquery import at the top of your main theme.liquid file. This acts as the base for every page on the site and is always loaded.